# AXIOS POST ERROR: "http://loclhost:5001/cartdata net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED"

Tags: post, react-redux, axios, redux-async-actions

I faced problem when I tried to connect my react-redux(redux thunk) project with my backend. I tried to post product_id and the quantity(qty) to my backend server. I checked server using Postman. It works properly. But from frontend, I got this "net::ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED" error.
The error message is given here:
[image]

I tried to do axios post in my cartActoin.js file. Here is the code of that addCart :

```
    export const addCart = (product) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { id, title, price, category, image, rating, description, qty } = product;

        const newProduct = {
            "productId": id,
            "qty": 1
        }
     
       // console.log("new", newProduct);
        let axiosConfig = {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(newProduct),
        };

        await axios.post("http://loclhost:5001/cartdata", newProduct, axiosConfig).then(()=>{
            dispatch({
                type: ActionTypes.ADD_CART,
                payload: product,
            })
        }).catch((err) => {
            console.log(err);
        });

    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

How can I solved this? Thank You.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have misspelt 'localhost' keyword in the URL when making the 'POST' request.

**Your URL**: 'http://loclhost:5001/cartdata'
**Correction**: 'http://localhost:5001/cartdata'